# WSO2 Api manager- Respose body data is null using API SDK

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I've created an API using WSO2 Api Manager and gave a backend application URL as a production URL. I'm getting 200 response code and Json responce body in web console of the API but when I use JAVA SDK of that API using client. I'm not able to get the response data even though I'm getting 200 response code.

The below mention java code I'm using to consume the API.

Thanks in Advance!

```
    DefaultApi defaultApiTest = new DefaultApi();
    ApiClient apiClient = defaultApi.getApiClient();
    apiClient.addDefaultHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    apiClient.addDefaultHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + "e88aa28a-4e0e-34a1-aec1-55616bf1e7a1");
    apiClient.setBasePath("<Production URL of the API>");
    defaultApiTest.setApiClient(apiClient);
    ApiResponse<?> response = defaultApiTest.getWithHttpInfo();
    if(null != response){ 
        JSON data = apiClient.getJSON();
        String value = data.toString();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code in java for consume the API?

Comment: @Ernesto I've modified the question with the mentioned Java code please take a look and help me out.

Comment: I'm using Apache HTTP Client and it work fine.

Comment: @Ernesto It worked, Thank you.